# getting object values to d3 graph

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am new to D3. Currently create a graph to show data from 3 csv files. All csv files are stored mongodb. Currently,I can get jquery running to show all the data. 
Is there anyway I can get year and the number to store in x asix (number), y asix (year)?

```
"result": [
    {
      "Country Name": "Albania", 
      "data": {
        "phones_sale_total": {
          "2000": "29800", 
          "2001": "393000", 
          "2002": "851000", 
          "2003": "1100000", 
          "2004": "1260000", 
          "2005": "1530000", 
          "2006": "1910000", 
        }, 
        "income_per_person": { 
          "2000": "1450", 
          "2001": "1350", 
          "2002": "1580", 
          "2003": "1470", 
          "2004": "1800", 
          "2005": "1720", 
          "2006": "1220", 
        }, 
        "household_spending_total": {
          "2000": "25000", 
          "2001": "30000", 
          "2002": "36000", 
          "2003": "42000", 
          "2004": "48000", 
          "2005": "54000", 
          "2006": "120000"
        }
      }
```

Comment: I don't think the data you offer is come from CSV file. This [Document](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/tree/v1.2.0) will do some help.

Comment: I have stored those 3 csv files to MongoDB, just using jquery to call the data